# WSL 2 VS code Segmentation fault

Tags: visual-studio-code, segmentation-fault, wsl-2

### Problem

The problem is that when running **VS code**
for wsl2, the following error occurs
`Segmentation fault`

```bash
$ code .
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: I solved this by renaming the `~/.vscode-server` directory to `~/.vscode-server.bak` and then re-opening VSC. I also tried a few things like re-creating my WSL instance, but as soon as I copied the contents of my home directory over, I got the segmentation fault again.

I have copied my extensions over from the .bak folder, so it is something else that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 7):

### Suggestion

1. Do this in the WSL console

```bash
sudo apt-get remove code
```

2. Remove VS code from windows [Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall)
3. Reload PC
4. Install VS Code on windows (don't forget to check "Add PATH") [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-vscode)
5. Reload PC
6. Do this in the WSL console

```bash
 rm -rf ~/.vscode-server
```

7. Do this in the WSL console

```bash
code .
```

---

After completing these steps, you should have vs code running without any problems. If you consider it necessary to skip the steps with restarting the PC, this is your right. I just wrote a sequence of actions that helped me solve the problem

Thanks for the decision to this guy: [Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/j3g7tq/comment/gdiaa4c/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: Steps 6 ( `rm -rf ~/.vscode-server` ) and 7 ( `code .`) on the WSL console were suffient to solve my problem using WSL 2 Windows 10 Host and Ubuntu 22.04 distro.